# ActionAdapter cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, eclipse, event-handling

I've started learning about event handlers and have tried to play around with some basic concepts. I have gotten a weird error in the following code.
I'm using Eclipse and get the following errors on the line where I try to add an ActionListener to the Button b:

*"The method addActionListener(ActionListener) in the type Button is not applicable for the type new ActionAdapter(){}"*

*"ActionAdapter cannot be resolved to a type"*

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class Test extends Frame{

private TextField text = new TextField(20);
Button b;
private int num_clicks = 0;

public static void main(String args[]){
Test appwind = new Test("title");
appwind.setSize(300,300);
appwind.setTitle("Irrelevant");
appwind.setVisible(true);
}

public Test(String title)
{
    super(title);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            public void WindowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);}});
    b = new Button("Click");
    add(b);
    add(text);
    b.addActionListener(
            new ActionAdapter()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    num_clicks++;
                    text.setText("number of times clicked: " + num_clicks);}
            });


}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapter classes are convenience classes provided when the underlying interface has 2 or more methods. `ActionListener` only has one method - Use `ActionListener` instead

```
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         ...
     }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've read somewhere that all the Listener interfaces have "Adapter" classes that implement the specific interface, so that you don't have to implement all the methods and can only override those methods that you need.

Comment: Isn't ActionListener an interface? Why can I use an instance of an interface in this case?

Comment: it is but you can use it to create an anonymous implementation